# Draw lines over 180 degrees in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are trying to draw maritime routes between ports, for that we generated a kml with the coordinates

If the route is less than 180 degrees (does not exceed 12 time zones) everthing is ok.

for example:

Costa Rica to India

[Image Route: Costa Rica -> India](http://lsanabria.000webhostapp.com/MapFail.html)

If the route exceeds 180 degrees, it is drawn erroneously.

[Image Route: Costa Rica -> India -> Japon](http://lsanabria.000webhostapp.com/MapOK.html)

[image: screenshot of bad polyline]

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

In this url you can see the examples:

http://lsanabria.000webhostapp.com/MapFail.html

http://lsanabria.000webhostapp.com/MapOK.html

These are the kmls used

http://lsanabria.000webhostapp.com/RouteFail.kml

http://lsanabria.000webhostapp.com/RouteOk.kml

They were tested on google earth and both are shown ok.

--HTML:--

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      #map { height: 100%; }
      html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="content-window"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
        });

        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'http://lsanabria.000webhostapp.com/RouteFail.kml',
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          map: map
        });

        kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(kmlEvent) {
            var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
            showInContentWindow(text);
        });

        function showInContentWindow(text) {
            var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
            sidediv.innerHTML = text;
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Asking StackOverflow community to write code for you is considered off-topic here. Please, provide the examples of code that you have tried

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  A point in the middle of the line segment that is greater than 180 degrees should fix it (making all the segments less than 180 degrees), but based on the picture provided, it doesn't look like that is the issue, but hard to tell from a picture.

Comment: Your KML parses OK with [geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=9.916615&lng=-319.604176&zoom=2&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://lsanabria.000webhostapp.com/RouteFail.kml), it is [KmlLayer that renders it incorrectly (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/et0z9fbw/)

Comment: I would expect to find an issue about this in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/558438), if you can't find one, add one.

Comment: I had tested it as well with GeoXML3 and found out it was working fine. Still your KML doesn't fully validate (try http://www.kmlvalidator.org/home.htm) so you might want to correct these issues and try again, but the `RouteOK` kml returns the same validation errors...

Comment: Thank you all for your comments

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="content-window"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
        })

        kml  = new geoXML3.parser({map: map});
        kml.parse('RouteFail.kml');

      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
```